# C# Issue sending message from Server to multiple Clients (Socket Programming)

Tags: c#, sockets

So I'm very interested in learning more sophisticated programming techniques and languages, and I've decided to further my study into C# by learning sockets and server programming.  I stumbled upon a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI) that i bet a lot of you have already seen or heard of, and it's, in my opinion, pretty good at explaining most of what's going on.

So my problem is specifically with essentially taking this code and making it a chat system that takes info from a client, sends it to the server, then from the server to ALL clients.  I've looked up any tutorials and other stack overflow pages to no avail, at least to me.  I can't seem to figure it out, and when someone has an answer they've simply written "Found a solution" and more or less left it at that.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874724/c-sharp-socket-server-send-to-all-clients-on-list) thread on SO, and I've tried what's been posted in there to no avail.  I've also done my fair share of searching through google and whatnot, and with being new to sockets and all that, it's definitely not the easiest thing.

## The Actual Problem

Here's my code for the server:

```
using static AppNameHere.ChatCommands;


namespace AppNameHere
{
    public partial class Host : Form
    {
        public static Host host = null;

        private static string response;

        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> _ClientSk = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket _Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        public Host()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Host_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetupServer();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            _Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, HostJoinSelect.portSelected));
            _Socket.Listen(HostJoinSelect.playerTotal + 2);
            _Socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AccCallback), null);
        }

        private static void AccCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket s = _Socket.EndAccept(iar);
            _ClientSk.Add(s);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected.");
            s.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecCallback), s);
            _Socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AccCallback), null);
        }

        private static void RecCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket s = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            int received = s.EndReceive(iar);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, dataBuf, 0, received);

            string t = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);

            foreach (Socket socket in _ClientSk)
            {
                response = ChatCommandParser(t);

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecCallback), socket);
            }
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket s = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            s.EndSend(iar);
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` at the top is just a class I made for converting text to something else, so it's no obstruction.  What really rustles my jimmies is the `foreach` loop that's, in theory, supposed to make it work, and it makes sense as **it should be going through all the clients and sending them all messages, but if a client sends a message, nothing happens on the other clients.  Only the original client gets the message back.**

So both debugging and troubleshooting have shown that it runs through BeginSend and such, but it still only sends a message to that same client that i typed into which is just weird.

Thanks in advance, and please, if you have an answer then explain it to me cause I'm still learning, so a fix and an explanation would be nice.

P.S. Yes I know I'm using TCP and not UDP.

**EDIT**:  The code I used for my client is in this pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/4WicEu2x

**EDIT 2**:  I have a feeling the main issue is that in my client code, I have the client listening for messages only ***AFTER*** it sends a message.  If this is it, then i'm dumber than a rock and would like to thank anyone who posted here telling me how to improve my program.

**EDIT 3**:  What I wrote in my second edit was correct.  If you're having an issue and you've followed the same guide I did in that youtube video, then just know that you should have Asynchronous Receiving in your client-side program as well as your server.  I didn't think too much of the client side, but always check your code!  Here's my edited client-side code (yes i know it needs LOTS of work):

```
namespace AppNameHere
{
    public partial class Join : Form
    {
        public static Join join = null;

        private static Socket _ClientSk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        private static byte[] recBuf = new byte[1024];

        public Join()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Join_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Join_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (HostJoinSelect.hjs != null)
            {
                HostJoinSelect.hjs.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                HostJoinSelect.hjs = new HostJoinSelect();
                HostJoinSelect.hjs.Show();
            }
        }

        private void Join_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoopConnect();
        }

        private static void Send()
        {
            string req = join.textBox1.Text;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
            _ClientSk.Send(buffer);
        }

        private static void ConnectedCallback()
        {
            _ClientSk.BeginReceive(recBuf, 0, recBuf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallback), _ClientSk);
        }

        private static void ReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket s = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            int rec = s.EndReceive(iar);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[rec];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(recBuf, 0, dataBuf, 0, rec);

            string q = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);

            join.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                join.listBox1.Items.Add(Form1.namesave + ": " + q);
                join.listBox1.TopIndex = join.listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }));

            s.BeginReceive(recBuf, 0, recBuf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallback), s);
        }

        private static void LoopConnect()
        {
            int attempts = 0;

            while (!_ClientSk.Connected)
            {
                if (attempts < 4)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        attempts++;
                        if (attempts <= 4)
                        {
                            _ClientSk.Connect(HostJoinSelect.IPSelectedJoin, HostJoinSelect.portSelectedJoin);
                            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                            ConnectedCallback();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            attempts = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SocketException s)
                    {
                        if (attempts <= 4)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(s.Message + " | Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            attempts = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You failed to connect to " + HostJoinSelect.IPSelectedJoin + ":" + HostJoinSelect.portSelectedJoin + ", please ensure you have a means of connecting to this address.");
                    join.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Send();
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the code from accepting messages only after it sent one itself to having an asynchronous `BeginReceive` to take in data sent by the server.  Always review your code and logic!

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what actually is in the list? And what is sent to where? Also you probably don’t want to `BeginReceive` inside the loop nor use the same buffer for every client.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have debugged and saw that, in the list, if i had **x** clients connected, the Length of the List would be **x**, and the for loop would run **x** times, as it should.  And as for the `BeginReceive` can you explain why it shouldn't be in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that your code requires some fixes it still works. I executed it in my test project and it worked as you want (almost, short of concurrency issues).

Required concurrency fixes:

1. As Emir Curtovic mentioned you shouldn't use a common buffer. Use local variable instead. If you want you can utilize the same buffers between connections using ThreadLocal or AsyncLocal class-level fields. It will be both thread-safe and reduce a heap fragmentation hazard.
2. You cannot just use List for sockets. It is not thread safe. There are at least two possible fixes: a) use a `lock {}` around the `_ClientSk.Add(s)` call or b) use [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).

If your client connections come simultaneously the last bug may cause the behavior that you described. However, there is also a possibility that your client code has some issues as well. If after introducing the fixes you still experience the issue please post your client code as well.

In general, there is more work to be done with your code. For example you should handle client disconnections. Currently it will just throw exceptions on `int received = s.EndReceive(iar)` call any time your client decides to close the connection. Besides handling the exception you will need to add to your protocol some way to perform a graceful connection closing. For example, by handling EOF symbol. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) you will find a nice code sample from MSFT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I understand that I'm lacking in some areas, like closing connections for instance, but i'm trying to figure things out one at a time.

I'm not quite following what you're getting at here, but from what I can piece together, which might be wrong entirely, this program shouldn't be asynchronous?  I also have no idea how this works for you, but doesn't work for me.  What's your client look like?  This is mine: https://pastebin.com/4WicEu2x

Reposted comment because I took too long to edit it previously.

Comment: So i found the solution in the client, apparently I was just too dumb to look at the client-side code.  Still, thanks a lot for getting this off the ground and getting me to look further into my code.  Also, I'll be applying a lot of what you've suggested fairly soon to continue learning.  Thanks lots!  I'll write the fix to my solution as an edit in the root post.

Comment: @EmirCurtovic, good luck with your project! About the client: I just used [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) with `-d blahblah` switch, it is a bit awkward but does the job:). Also your program should be asynchronous, given that it serves multiple clients, but access to the members of the class must be synchronized. For example, when two threads add elements to the same list at the same time then it may cause pretty ugly situation.